# A function that takes two arguments- a function f and a list l and applies the function over the elements of the list and returns them as a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function

I made a function:

```
def remove_trailing_newlines(s):
  s_clean = s.rstrip()
  return s_clean
```

This function will remove the trailing \n at end of string s.
Now I want to apply the same to every element (which is string) of a list.

I want to create a function `mapl(f, l)` where f is `remove_trailing_newlines()` and l is a list on which we have to apply f and return it as a list

For example:
on the list `l = ['Apple\n','banana\n','mango\n']`

I want the output as : `l = ['Apple','banana','mango']`
using the mapl(f,l) function

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for:

```
list(map(remove_trailing_newlines, l))
```

We can pass custom function and apply the function to each element of the list.

You can also directly call `rstrip` inside `map` as in @yatu's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to make a function like a builtin map function by yourself. Try the following:

```
def remove_trailing_newlines(s):
    s_clean = s.rstrip()

    return s_clean

def mapl(f,l):
    ret = []
    for i in l:
        ret.append(f(i))
    return ret

l = ['Apple\n','banana\n','mango\n']


new_list = mapl(remove_trailing_newlines,l)
print(new_list)

>> ['Apple', 'banana', 'mango']
```

Let me know if it does not fulfill your requirement